# Migrate data from ASP.Net Membership Provider to System.Web.Providers

Tags: asp.net-membership, azure-sql-database

I am migrating an existing asp.net mvc application to Azure and would like to use the System.Web.Providers for membership.

Is there any existing tool or recipe to Migrate data from the ASP.Net Membership Provider to System.Web.Providers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a  post on .NET Web Development and Tools Blog
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/16/migration-for-user-accounts-from-the-sqlmembershipprovider-to-the-universal-providers.aspx
which explains in detail how to move your data and what Web.Config attributes to touch.

basically what you need is a bunch of SQL statements

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Applications (ApplicationName, ApplicationId, Description)
SELECT ApplicationName, ApplicationId, Description FROM dbo.aspnet_Applications
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Roles (ApplicationId, RoleId, RoleName, Description)
SELECT ApplicationId, RoleId, RoleName, Description FROM dbo.aspnet_Roles
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Users (ApplicationId, UserId, UserName, IsAnonymous, LastActivityDate)
SELECT ApplicationId, UserId, UserName, IsAnonymous, LastActivityDate FROM dbo.aspnet_Users
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Memberships (ApplicationId, UserId, Password, 

PasswordFormat, PasswordSalt, Email, PasswordQuestion, PasswordAnswer, 

IsApproved, IsLockedOut, CreateDate, LastLoginDate, LastPasswordChangedDate, 

LastLockoutDate, FailedPasswordAttemptCount, 

FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart, FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount, 

FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart, Comment) 
SELECT ApplicationId, UserId, Password, 

PasswordFormat, PasswordSalt, Email, PasswordQuestion, PasswordAnswer, 

IsApproved, IsLockedOut, CreateDate, LastLoginDate, LastPasswordChangedDate, 

LastLockoutDate, FailedPasswordAttemptCount, 

FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart, FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount, 

FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart, Comment FROM dbo.aspnet_Membership
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.UsersInRoles SELECT * FROM dbo.aspnet_UsersInRoles
GO
```

You will also have to add `passwordCompatMode="Framework20"` attribute to membership provider configuration.